# how does composer for binance API for PHP work?

Tags: php, api, xampp, composer-php

I try to get this done from github.
https://github.com/binance-exchange/php-binance-api

I installed Xampp (latest version: 7.2.3) on a win 10 machine. Xampp is running. (at least not mysql, because it has an error while starting, but mysql is not needed).
I downloaded the files from github and puttet them into my htdocs in a new folder called "binance".
I downloaded the install-file for composer from here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows
Installed it and choosed the php.exe out of my xampp folder inside the installation-process.

Composer starts out of the console, and it works.
I put this command into the cmd:

```
php composer.phar require "jaggedsoft/php-binance-api @dev"
```

It installs some folders and files, but not into my project-directory. It downloads and installs it into "user/vendor/..." on my drive c.

Inside of the files downloaded from github, there is a file called:
php-binance-api-test.php

Inside this file, there are different lines like:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
file_put_contents( getenv("HOME") . "/.config/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api.json" ,
```

I copied the whole vendor directory into my project directory, so he can find his files.
But he is not able to find ".config/jaggedsoft/" because there is no folder named .config. 
There is also no file named php-binance-api.json only one called php-binance-api.php

If I try to access some of the sample file, like web_socket_chart.php in examples,  he gives me an fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\EventLoop\Factory' not found in
```

...

this might be a file inside of the php-folder of xampp, but how does he load it before to get the class nedded?

I think i messed up the installation of composer? or do I have to choose other place for the project inside of xampp?

What is composer even good for? I would be really thankful, if someone may try to get this run an tell me, what I have done wrong.

Comment: You need to run composer from the root folder of the project

Comment: you mean, I have to switch in the cmd to the rootfolder and then make the installing thing?... I try it later.